# Excel date format issue when copied form DB to Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am copying data which is a result of sql query to an excel sheet. There is no issues with copying the data to the excel sheet. In one of the columns there is a date which looks like 00:00.0 but when I double click on the column it gives me the actual date format:  1/25/2019 8:00 AM.

I cannot double click on each column to get the data populated. Is there a way we can get this done as it will take lot of time to double click each column.

Comment: Please see if custom formatting cells `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM` helps in the matter

Comment: yes its the same format and i am updating the solution for it

Answer (score 0):

I think this is to do with the column width being too small to show you what is inside. 
Try this:

- Select the column or columns that you want to change.
- On the Home tab, in the Cells group, click Format.
- Under Cell Size, click AutoFit Column Width.

This should set it to auto fit what is inside. 
[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-column-width-and-row-height-72f5e3cc-994d-43e8-ae58-9774a0905f46).

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestions appreciate it but its another option.
- Home Tab-> Format-> format cells
- select Date-> select format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM and click ok it will convert the data to the actual format.

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this `Columns("A:Z").Autofit` command at the end of your code.  You will need to reference your workbook, worksheet and the columns you want to re-size.

Comment: appreciate the suggestion but i figured it out thank you.